# Div height in percentage, half parent height

Tags: css

I have two divs displayed next to each other, left div is `20%` width and right is `80%` width.

Now left div contains image which is resized horizontally so it's height is unknown and keeps changing.

Now when this div resizes parent height increases or decreases, so when that happens i need my right div to resize as well, how can i do that?

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UJYyw/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to do this.

```
$('.container').css({'height':$('.one').height()});​
```

[See a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UJYyw/6/)

When you change the value of `.one` in the css, it will update the size of `.container`, and thus, `.two` as well.

Comment: Yeah, i knew how to do that myself, but since other people either didn't understood what i need or they just made incorrect answer on purpose i will accept your answer, even thou i really wanted css solution

Answer (score 2):

You can try the CSS3 `table-cell` value on the `display` property : http://jsfiddle.net/UJYyw/5/

With

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

You just have to apply a `table-cell` display on `div.one` and `div.two`

```
.one, .two{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Compliant browsers will adapt height of elements the way they do on `td` and `th` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the crossbrowser solution which uses just floats and couple of wrappers http://jsfiddle.net/RSPbD/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrap1">
        <div class="wrap2">
            <div class="one">text in div one</div>
            <div class="two">text in div two</div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
    border:1px solid;
    width:70%;
    margin:50px;
    padding:10px;
}

.wrap1 {
    width: 25%;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 7%;
}

.wrap2 {
    width: 200%;
    position: relative;
    left: 100%;
    margin:0 -200% 0 0;
    background: blue;
}

.one{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: -100%;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}

.two {
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```